# Reversing IQueryable based on passed property for sorting logic

Tags: linq

I am implementing sort based on parameter passed to ascending or descending OrderBy method

```
  else if (showGrid.Sortdir == "DESC")
                    {
                        alerts = DB.Incidents.OfType<Alert>().Where(
                            a =>
                            a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.New ||
                            a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.Assigned ||
                            a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.Watching)
                            .OrderByDescending(a => showGrid.Sort);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alerts = DB.Incidents.OfType<Alert>().Where(
                            a =>
                            a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.New ||
                            a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.Assigned ||
                            a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.Watching)
                            .OrderBy(a => showGrid.Sort);
                    }
```

In case of ascending order sorting it works fine but for descending order sorting doesn't work. I debugged the code and I found that list is not revered its same as ascending order. Please help me

Comment: Sounds like `Sortdir` isn't exactly "DESC" then. I suggest you put logging in both branches (or debug into the code) to see which path is actually taken.

Comment: I already tired that it is using respective path for "ASC" and "DESC". while debug I put watch for 'alerts' values I can see that the items  are not revered  when its executes OrderByDesending(a=>showGrid.Sort);

Comment: And what is `showGrid.Sort`? What kind of LINQ provider are you using to start with?

Comment: ShowGrid.Sort is type of string which returns property name like "AlertNumber", "IncidentStatusID" etc. on basis of which I want to sort 'alert' list.
I am using System.Linq 
version: v4.0.0.0 and Runtime version:v4.0.30319

Comment: Sorting does not work like you want. When you send `a => showGrid.Sort`, it will take `Sort` as the property on which to sort. It seems, that your `Alert` object incidentally have such property. And that is why you project even compile.

Comment: Thats make seance Vladimir. I will test with this perspective and let you know. Thank you very much for your responses Vladimir and Jon. See you soon

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've written a small test. It is funny, but your code can actually compile and work, but very differently from what you expect :)
Obviously `showGrid` is not of type `Alert`, it is an instance of some other class, that incidentally have the same propery as `Alert`, called Sort.
First I was confused, because  expected this code to fail to compile.

```
// The signature of OrderBy
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)

// In your case it will result in
public static IOrderedQueryable<Alert> OrderBy<Alert, string>(this IQueryable<Alert> source, Expression<Func<Alert, string>> keySelector)
//when you call it like you do
DB.Incidents.OfType<Alert>().OrderByDescending(a => showGrid.Sort);
// You supply a property from object of type different from your entity.
// This is incorrect usage, the only object you can use here is the
// "a" argument. Like this:
DB.Incidents.OfType<Alert>().OrderByDescending(a => a.Sort);
// Because anything else does not make any sense to entity provider.
```

So your order by simply does not work.

As far as I understood, what you want is to perform sorting based on selection in UI. This is not easily achieved in strongly-typed LINQ. Because as I showed above, you send a property, not a value to the OrderBy. It does not care about the value inside the prop. So there are several solutions to the problem:

1. Write a big switch, that will check every possible Sort value, and will append appropriate 'OrderBy(a => a.YouPropToSort)' to the query. This is straitforward, and you should begin with this. Of course this is a static way, and will require to change code everytime you want new columns to be added for sorting.
2. Create argument for your OrderBy using 'LINQ Expression Trees'. For you case it should not be very hard to do. Look for the term, you will find a lot of examples.
3. Try to use Dynamic LINQ. I did not not use it myself, just looked at the docs. This seems to be an extension to the normal LINQ which allows you to write parts of queries as strings, to overcome limitations like the current one with dynamic sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to sorting based on user selections:

Create your base query

```
var query = DB.Incidents.OfType<Alert>.Where(
                       a =>
                       a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.New ||
                       a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.Assigned ||
                       a.IncidentStatusID == (int)AlertStatusType.Watching);
```

and then apply your sort using a case statement

```
bool desc = showGrid.SortDir = "DESC";

switch(showGrid.Sort)
{
   case "col1":
       query = desc ? query.OrderByDescending( a => a.Col1 ) : query.OrderBy( a => a.Col1 );
       break;
   case "col2":
       query = desc ? query.OrderByDescending( a => a.Col2 ) : query.OrderBy( a => a.Col2 );
       break;
   ...
}

var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: This is not correct. `OfType` is supported by `Queryable` in order to get specific derieved entities, it will not iterate the collection.

Comment: ok, I stand corrected.  I'll have to test this to convince myself, but don't have time right now.  Changed answer accordingly.

Comment: Here's a quote from Queryable source: `public static IQueryable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IQueryable source)` so you can be sure :)